# Formatting column in alternating colours, conditional on text in Row 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I need the formatting to change depending on the day of the week. I also want the formatting to alternate colour by line, to help break it up. It should look like this:

[image]

I have some code which formats specific ranges of columns to format in the alternating colours:

```
'Colour Sundays alternate light grey / dark grey
For Each cell In Range("AX1:AX" & lastRow)
If cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Else
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
End If
Next cell
```

However, this isn't particularly agile, since I want to be able to run this report over any number of weeks (up to a year), and hard coding specific cell ranges would mean repeating the same code 52 times.

I also have the following code which I've used for cell widths:

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Cell1 As Range

Set Range1 = Range("O1:QA1")

For Each Cell1 In Range1
If Cell1 Like "*Mon*" Or Cell1 Like "*Tue*" Then
Cell1.ColumnWidth = 7.86

End If
Next Cell1

For Each Cell1 In Range1
If Cell1 Like "*Wed*" Or Cell1 Like "*Thu*" Then
Cell1.ColumnWidth = 7.86

End If
Next Cell1

For Each Cell1 In Range1
If Cell1 Like "*Fri*" Or Cell1 Like "*Sat*" Then
Cell1.ColumnWidth = 7.86

End If
Next Cell1
```

Which I'm using for coding the column widths (this isn't great either - I can't work out how to make it count all the weekdays in the same section of code, but it works so I'm happy to leave it).

Is there any way to combine this code so that it reads: If the cell in Row 1 contains Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, change column width and format in alternating colours? And the same for Sundays etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a table which will automatically shade alternate rows?

Comment: @SJR Thanks for the code below - really helpful! How do I code a table to work dependent on the text at the top? I could run a report which is either a couple of days long, or an entire year, so the number of weeks is going to vary greatly

Comment: You can use the `headerrowrange` property of the table to check the first row.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above, but you can shorten your loops to this:

```
Sub x()

Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Cell1 As Range

Set Range1 = Range("O1:QA1")

For Each Cell1 In Range1
    Select Case True
        Case celll Like "*Sun*"
            Cell1.ColumnWidth = 8
        Case else
            Cell1.ColumnWidth = 7.86
    End Select
Next Cell1

End Sub
```

Thanks to Zac for pointing out even shorter code.

Comment: Could you just check `Case celll Like "*Sun*"` and set rest on `Case Else`?

Comment: TBH i didn't read all of OP's requirement so wasn't sure if that was a requirement or not :)